# Pass parameters using POST to HTML page from SSRS

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a HTML page stored as web resource in CRM 2013. I have a report from which I need to pass all records guids to this HTML page. I am able to pass the record guids(Comma separated list) successfully. However, when the URL length exceeds 2000 characters, I am getting a "404 Resource not found" error. This is due to URL length limit. Is there a way I can pass the record guids using POST method to HTML page from SSRS which will work for any number of records?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach seems to be storing the record guids as a variable on the SSRS report via something like

```
=Code.WriteHTML("<script>window.recordGuids=[" & recordIds & "];</script>")
```

and then in the web resource use something like

```
var ids = window.opener.recordGuids;
```

But that will likely only work in the browser and the report would have to be viewed from CRM.

Otherwise, you could do a post to an external service, which could launch the web page and allow getting the ids through a caching mechanism mixed with a jsonp call of some sort.

Comment: Thank you very much BlueSam for the reply. But, the HTML web resource is stored in CRM and I need to pass the GUIDS of report records to HTML. So, in this case, how to pass the variable which stores all GUIDS to HTML. Can you kindly provide some sample code to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you need to pass it in? Why can't you use the example that I gave above? var ids = window.opener.recordGuids;

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to write a custom code which will send a HTML response including recordIDS when I click the hyperlink and then I need to manipulate the HTML response to access record GUIDs.